# Stop apache2 phpmyadmin

Tags: cloud9-ide

Hi i'm using ruby on rails with thin in cloud9 with command

```
rails s -p $PORT -b $IP
```

it run correcly.

But after i installed phpmyadmin with:

```
phpmyadmin-ctl install
```

if i try to launch

```
rails s -p $PORT -b $IP
```

it tell me that the port is already used. How can i stop apache?

I've tried with

```
service apache2 stop
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to kill apache with sudo

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

You won't be able to run both phpmyadmin and rails at the same time as they both need port 8080 but you can switch between (by stopping one and running the other).

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is an application that needs to be served through a webserver (like Apache) the package you installed probably bundled it's own apache instance causing some kind of port conflict.

Though I think the best way of using phpMyAdmin is not using a bundled package, you can probably stop apache with the control interface:

```
apachectl stop
```

or:

```
apache2ctl stop
```

If this doesn't work either you can probably kill it the hard way. First find out which PID (Process ID) Apache is running with by typing something like:

```
ps faux | grep apache
```

By running "ps faux" as a root or privileged user you can see the system's running processes. Filtering results to only match "apache" makes it a lot easier to read.

When you've found the PID you can stop it "the hard way" by running:

```
kill <PID>
```

Note that this is not the recommended way as it could potentially cause trouble.